# Accessibility in Age of Empires II

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd, accessibility

Is it possible to play Age of Empires II with only a mouse and left-click? I've accessibility limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can.**

Make sure you turn off 'Two Button Mouse' in the Options:

[image]

This will allow you to select and order all units.

I think most options should be available this way. You will probably have to make intensive use of the menu in the lower left corner.
Double-click selects all units of the same category in the visible area.

The most annoying thing I found in a short playthrough was the inability to unselect units: the best way to do this is to left-click and drag in an area without selectable units.